# Passing JSON through AJAX to PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have some json that I want to pass through to another php file using ajax.

```
{
"id":"5",
"itemName":"Infinity",
"itemDesc":"Infinity",
"imageURL":"Infinity.jpg",
"language":"N\/A",
"category":"Logos",
"size":"612 KB",
"flagDesc":"",
"fileType":"jpg"
}
```

Here is my ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url:'download.php',
  data: {
  image: z,
},
  success:function(results){
  alert(results);
}
});
```

Z represents the json above. I'm not sure what to put when passing data. I've been going back and forth and no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:'download.php',
    data: { image: JSON.stringify(z) },
    success:function(results){
        alert(results);
    }
});
```

And in your `download.php`, you can access this data as

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['image']);
```

Comment: Okay, I am seeing the data on my alert, but what does stringify do?

Comment: It just makes it into a string..I see.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(input)` converts the input into a string in order to be able to pass that string over the network. When the server (php in your case) recieves this string, simply convert back to the json(associative array or stdClass in php) by calling json_decode($_POST['image']).

Comment: `JSON.stringify` converts a string to json so it does not do much (nothing...) if you already have valid json.

Comment: When doing a var_dump on my download.php file, it only gives me one array from the json_decode($_POST['image'], true);

I want both of the arrays getting passed.

Comment: It should work. Make sure that your are not calling `$.ajax` five times. And what you mean by both 2 arrays. You have only one stdClass of object after `json_decode`. You should use data as `$data = json_decode($_POST['image']); echo $data->imageURL;`, for example. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If `z` is all you want to pass, I would do:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'download.php',
  data: z,
  success:function(results){
    alert(results);
  }
});
```

In php you can do: `$image = json_encode($_GET);` if you would need your data to be json.

Comment: However, he wants to pass the data with the `image` keyword.

Comment: @Tolga Akyüz I am assuming the OP has control over the back-end as well as it is on the same server. So the name is not important.

Comment: don't use GET for arbitrarily long data. it's likely to get chopped off by a browser and/or server and corrupt the data completely.

Comment: @jeroen You are right, the name is not important, he just ask in a that way. He may need to use `image` keyword specifically.

Comment: @Marc B I know, but as the OP did not specify a type, it will default to GET so that's what I used...

Comment: 'image' is just a simple key I used for reference on the download.php page

Comment: I suggest you to use my way. Since, giving a key like `image` is a convenient way to access the data and `POST` method much more reliable than `GET`.

Comment: @wowzuzz To be clear, the comments about using POST are spot-on, you should definitely switch to POST if it is possible.